# Node-Red Bit to Word Node

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-red, modbus, modbus-tcp

Looking for a node that can join 16 bits into a word for writing over Modbus TCP.

I am using the 16Bit Split node for reading each bit from a Modbus Flex Getter and wanted a similar functionality to be used with Modbus Flex Write.

Attempted to make one myself using multiple function nodes but was unsuccessful getting the sum of a string array that would change size depending on the amount of inputs.

See attached pictures. Thanks
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]